# Multiple key value pairs for a dictionary within dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, string-formatting

I have a csv file with a bunch of lines ordered like this: Individual#,ResultType,Count:

1,RESULT004,171
1,RESULT005,71
2,RESULT001,12
2,RESULT004,981
...

My goal is to eventually make a human readable table with the individuals on the rows and the number of times they had each result as the columns. If they did not have a result, I would like a zero there. Like this:

Individual1,0,0,0,171,71
Individual2,12,0,0,981,0

I am struggling with the best way to do this. I first tried to read the file in as a list of lists, and I can kind of make the table, but without the zeros when there was no matching test results, by doing this:

```
import csv
individuals = [1,2,13,15,91]
resultlist = ['RESULT001', 'RESULT002', 'RESULT003', 'RESULT004', 'RESULT005']
intermediatelist = []
datafile = open(infile, 'rU')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
for row in datareader:
   intermediatelist.append(row)    
for individual in individualslist:
   resultfile.write(str(individual) + ',')
   for result in resultlist:
      for row in intermediatelist:
         if str(individual) == row[0] and result == row[1]:
            resultfile.write(result + ',' + str(row[2]) + ',')
   resultfile.write('\n')
```

When I tried to specify what happens when a match for the RESULT wasn't found, then I end up writing too many things to the file (e.g. whenever the individual and the RESULT do not match, which is often). Thinking about this more, it seems like a dictionary would be the way to go instead. In (kind of) pseudocode:

```
for individual in individual list:
   outfile.write(individual)
   for test in testlist:
      if test in ditionary_for_individual1:
         outfile.write(dictionary_for_individual1[test])
      else:
         outfile.write('0')
```

I'm having trouble reading in my file as a dictionary composed of dictionaries for each individual and accessing it correctly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not very pythonic, but I made a script to write out the code for making a dictionary for each individual (e.g. `individual1 = {RESULT004:171, RESULT005:71}` and so on.) But now I am stuck again. I have my list of individuals but I can't figure out how to call the dictionary with the same name to look up the key:value pair.

Comment: Maybe I need to learn string formatting?

Comment: please avoid commenting under your own question while you could just add this to your question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate values in a simple `dict` subclass using the [`__missing__` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__) so the formatted user ID is always part of resulting sub-`dict`. Then write them back using a [`DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) that can look up the necessary fields automatically, as well as filling in the missing values automatically:

```
import csv

# Make a dict subclass that autovivifies child dict with user field filled in
class AutoUserDict(dict):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __missing__(self, key):
        '''Expects int user ID, formats as Individual###'''
        self[key] = ret = {'user': 'Individual{}'.format(key)}
        return ret

resultlist = ['RESULT001', 'RESULT002', 'RESULT003', 'RESULT004', 'RESULT005']
intermediateresults = AutoUserDict()

with open(infile, 'rb') as datafile:
    datareader = csv.reader(datafile)
    for user, rslttype, value in datareader:
        # Store new rslttype (will create subdict with formatted user first if needed)
        intermediateresults[int(user)][rslttype] = int(value)

with open(outfile, 'rb') as outf:
    datawriter = csv.DictWriter(outf, fieldnames=['user']+resultlist, restval='0')
    for user, data in sorted(intermediateresults.items()):
        datawriter.writerow(data)
```

Comment: isn't the `dict.__missing__` hook doing kind of the same than collections.defaultdict ?

Comment: @Apero: Yes, but the `__missing__` hook gives you access to the `key` you tried to access, allowing us to construct the `user` field only once (on first access to the key), where `defaultdict` only takes a zero argument callable that can't compute the default value in terms of the key. If you used `defaultdict(dict)`, you'd have to change `intermediateresults[int(user)][rslttype] = int(value)` to something like `intermediateresults[int(user)].update({'user': 'Individual{}'.format(user), rslttype: int(value)})` that redundantly formats & sets the `user` field to ensure it's populated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the functionality of 2D array with dictionnaries

```
individuals = []
results = []
counts = {}
# read data
with open(inp_file_name,'r') as inp_file:
  for inp_line in inp_file:
    inp_list = inp_line.strip().split(','):
    i,r,c = inp_list
    if i not in individuals: individuals.append(i)
    if r not in results: results.append(r)
    counts[i,r] = int(c)
# optional sort 
individuals.sort()
results.sort()
# print data
with open(out_file_name,'w') as out_file:
  # header
  out_list = [''] + results
  out_file.write( "%s\n" % (" ".join(out_list)))
  # table
  for i in individuals:
    out_list = [ i ]
    for r in results:
      c = counts.get((i,r),0)  
      out_list.append( "%d" % c )
    out_file.write( "%s\n" % (" ".join(out_list)))
```

This assumes each combination of individual/result occurs once.  Otherwise change to `counts[i,r] = int(c) + counts.get((i,r,),0)`.

You can also change the separator for `","` or  `"\t"` for the two `join`.

It also takes advantage of the fact that `count[i,r]` is equivalent to `count[(i,r)]` (the key of the dict element is a 2-tuple).

You could add some error checking.